# Can't call a variable inside os.system method in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
ENV=raw_input("Enter Environment (QA/Prod):")
print(ENV) 
os.system('aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Environment,Values=ENV" "Name=instance-state-code, Values=16" > FilteredOP')
```

Hi,
I am quite noob to Python. Here,
I cannot able to call ENV variable in os.system command. Is there anything wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `ENV` won't get magically substituted in the string like so.

Consider the following:

```
>>> ENV = 'debug'
>>>
>>> 'Value=ENV'
'Value=ENV'
>>>
>>> 'Value={}'.format(ENV)
'Value=debug'
```

So instead of *hardcoding* `ENV` as part of the string, you want to insert the value of `ENV` using *string formatting*:

```
os.system('...Values=.{}...'.format(ENV))
```

However, [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is a cleaner alternative you may want to *check out*.

Answer (score 0):

Read about formatting output, In yours ENV considered as string "ENV".

```
ENV=raw_input("Enter Environment (QA/Prod):")
print(ENV) 
os.system('aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Environment,Values={}" "Name=instance-state-code, Values=16" > FilteredOP'.format(ENV))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ENV=raw_input("Enter Environment (QA/Prod):")
    print(ENV) 
    os.system('aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Environment,Values=%s" "Name=instance-state-code, Values=16" > FilteredOP'%(ENV))
```